# How to get List Layer Filters in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I trying to get list layer filters option in Magento 1 in custom file name is `list_layer_options.php`. This is my source:

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters(); 
var_dump($appliedFilters);
```

It's return `array(0)`, so how can get list layer option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

foreach ($appliedFilters as $filter) {
    var_dump($filter->getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Price,  it return `array(0) {}` so not foreach

Comment: Basically have you some filter in your layered navigation ?

Comment: brand, sales, color, price.

Comment: And you well that filters in front ?

Comment: no, I asked how do get it?

Comment: Yes i know Im talking about a layered navigation in front, do you see them

Comment: yes I saw them.